# DataTable en blanco

Tags: datatables, aspx

Tengo este query el cual solo quiero trae 3 datos, y lo que tenga quiero ponerlo en un DataTable.

```
private DataTable getData()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT id, name,Address from employees";
            DataTable dt = dbCapa.dtSeleccDatos(sql);
            return dt;
        }
```

La function anterior lleva a esta:

```
public string getDataTable()
        {
            string ret = "";
            DataTable dt = getData();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                ret = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" });
            else
                ret = "[]";
            return ret;
        }
```

Al hacer un debug, no estoy recibiendo ningun dato a partir de la consulta, por lo que se va a el lado falso 'ret = "[]";' y regresa un json vacio.

Que me falta en la primera function donde esta la consulta para que me regrese todos los datos?

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate que la conexión a la base de datos este correcta, no veo que se este llamando la conexión por ningún lado.